# How to parameterize write_disposition on a BigQueryOperator?

Tags: google-bigquery, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I'm a trying to adapt a current pipeline on jenkins to be orchestrated by airflow.
One of our needs, is to be able to reprocess historical data, over a loop of dates, by a manual trigger.

Assuming I just added a new stage on my pipe/dag, and I would like to execute it for the past n days, not changing already created tables, I could just set all BigQueryOperators to work on write_disposition: 'WRITE_EMPTY'

I understand that if write_disposition was a templatable field, it would be just simple as that:

```
BigQueryOperator(
            task_id="table_x",
            bql='sql_folder/my_query.sql',
            destination_dataset_table="project_id.dataset_id.my_table_{{ dag_run.conf["date_suffix"] }}",
            write_disposition='{{ dag_run.conf["write_disposition"] }}',
            params={
                 'event_date': "{{ dag_run.conf["event_date"] }}"
            }
        )
```

Calling the dag on a loop of dates:

```
airflow trigger_dag 'example_dag_conf' -r 'run_id' --conf '{"date_suffix":"20191213", "event_date":"2019-12-13", "write_disposition": ""}'
```

But it is not.

Is there any workaround on that? Or a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a **CustomBigQueryOperator** that inherits from **BigQueryOperator** for your use case.

Example:

```py
class CustomBigQueryOperator(BigQueryOperator):
    template_fields = ('sql', 'destination_dataset_table', 'labels', 'write_disposition')
```

and use that in your DAG.

Comment: Nice @kaxil! Thanks! Any idea if it is possible to pass any exception args to the jinja template? I mean something like: from datetime import datetime ; {{ dag_run.conf["date_suffix"] if dag_run else datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')}}.